# Problem Fieldset label not visible with Sencha ExtJs 7.x on chrome 87.0.4280.67

Tags: extjs

I have a problem with chrome 87.0.4280.67 and Sencha ExtJs 7.x, after chrome update Fieldset label are not visible.

I can see the problem in the official kitchensink examples:
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-fieldcontaine

Comment: css class x-fieldset overflow is set to hidden, changing this to visible will work, but not sure which side effects may be caused by that change

Comment: Extjs 5 also has the same problem. BTW in kitchensink example if you toggle chrome dev tools label appears, if it is expanded...

Comment: Seems, Chrome fixed the issue. Working fine in 87.0.4280.88

Comment: Just wanted to link to an open issue for this when this was a Safari only issue - https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?423768-ExtJS-6-5-0-Fieldset-legend-are-not-visible-in-Safari-11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Sencha Support, the best solution is:

```
.x-fieldset-header, .x-fieldset-header-default > .x-fieldset-header-text {
    position: initial;
}

.x-fieldset-header, .x-fieldset-header-default .x-tool-tool-el {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

I've tested it on Ext 7.3.1 and 6.5.3

Comment: In some cases .x-fieldset (overflow: initial) is needed. Without it you wont be able to scroll through large fieldsets.

Answer (score 4):

We fixed it by adding

> position:static

or

> position: unset // (thanks to mitchell)

to

> .x-fieldset-header-default > .x-fieldset-header-text

I tested it in ExtJS 6.2.1 and 7.3.1 in Chrome, Firefox and Edge and it works at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the checkbox if `checkboxToggle: true` https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.form.FieldSet.html#cfg-checkboxToggle

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it with

```
.x-fieldset-header,
.x-fieldset-header .x-tool-tool-el {
    overflow: unset;
}
```

Using only the position technique in @Gasper's answer worked for fieldsets that had only labels, but with collapsible fieldsets the expand/collapse icon was still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only one which works well, and does not affect Safari is just a simple:

```
.x-fieldset {
    overflow: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the below code:

```
.x-fieldset-header, .x-fieldset-header-default .x-tool-tool-el {
    overflow: static;
}
```